# Why does all.equal show a mean relative difference in the numeric column between 2 datasets but

Tags: r

calculating the mean of the 2 columns separately shows that they are the same?

I cannot replicate this on a made-up data set and the dataset is propriety. And that is the only comment that showed up.

There are NA in data, some rows are not in the same order.

Has anyone else encountered this?

Based on the comment below, I have refined my question:
My motivation is to see if there is any difference in output for between:

1)

```
merged_dt1= merge.data.table(dta, dtb, all = T, by = c("col1", "col2"))

merged_dt2= merge.data.table(merged_dt1, dtc, all = T, by = c("col1", "col2"))
```

2. 

```
merged_dt1= merge(dta[, .(col1, col2)], dtb[, .(col1, col2)], 
all = TRUE, by = c("col1", "col2")))

merged_dt2 = merge(merged_dt1, dta, all.x = TRUE, by = c("col1", "col2"))
  
merged_dt2 = merge(merged_dt2 , dtb, all.x = TRUE, by = c("col1", "col2"))
 
merged_dt3 = merge(merged_dt1, dtc, all = TRUE, by = c("col1", "col2"))
 
merged_dt4 = merge(merged_dt3 , merged_dt2, all = TRUE, keyby = c("col1", "col2"))
```

Comment: Could you share your code?

Comment: I am not too sure if it helps, I just have 2 data sets, cobbled together in different ways, and used all.equal(dt1, dt2).

Both data sets have the same number of rows and columns. The only message I received was regarding the numeric column being different to the tune of 0.6xxx.

Individually calcuating the columns shows that the mean is the same.